# Design Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, sass

I have problem with scss. I want design my scrollbar, but does not display my design. I am new in SCSS.

```css
.sublist {
   @at-root &__list {
      @extend %relative;
      background-color: $main-black;
      border: none;
      padding: 30px;
      max-height: 384px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;

      &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
           background: red;
      }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe your problem clearly.

Comment: I want change scrollbar design, but if I add  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb in my code It is not change design. Did I add a pseudo class wall?

Comment: `-webkit-scrollbar` is a nonstandard and poorly supported css property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar, personally I wouldn't use it if I were you since your users will have inconsistent user experience. So, take into account that you'll see problems on some browsers, make sure you are testing that on browsers that actually supports that.

Comment: Ahaa okey thank you for suggestion, but I use new -v Chrome.

Comment: _"but I use new -v Chrome"_ And all of your users do too?